# Populating Text area using button slection

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextarea

I'm trying to have text displayed depending on which button is selected, but I can't seem to get it to work,

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package nameage;

/**
 *
 * @author Eddie
 */
public class NameAge extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NameAge
     */
    public NameAge() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Name:");

        jLabel2.setText("Age Group:");

        buttonGroup1.add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setLabel("0 - 19");

        jButton2.setText("20 - 29");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton2);

        jButton3.setText("30 - 39");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton3);

        jButton4.setText("40 - 49");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton4);

        jButton5.setText("50 - 59");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton5);

        jButton6.setText("70 - 79");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton6);

        jButton7.setText("60 - 69");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton7);

        jButton8.setText("80 - 89");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton8);

        jButton9.setText("90 - 99");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton9);

        jButton10.setText("100 +");
        buttonGroup1.add(jButton10);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addGap(17, 17, 17))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                                    .addComponent(jButton7))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton8)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton9)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton5)))
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 357, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton9)
                    .addComponent(jButton10))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>




//THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO DISPLAY


       private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           jTextPane1.setText("Hello " + jTextField1 + "\n You've still got a lot of livin' left to do!");
       }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameAge.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameAge.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameAge.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NameAge.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NameAge().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it will print something like

> Hello avax.swing.JTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@58372a00,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]
>   You've still got a lot of livin' left to do!

Or some such.

This is because you're using

```
jTextPane1.setText("Hello " + jTextField1 + "\n You've still got a lot of livin' left to do!");
```

Which automatically calls the  `jTextField1`'s `toString` method (nice feature when you're use to it).

Instead you should be using `JTextField#getText` to get the text that the field contains, for example...

```
jTextPane1.setText("Hello " + jTextField1.getText() + "\n You've still got a lot of livin' left to do!");
```

The other problem is, there is nothing calling the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method to actually print anything.

You need to attach an `ActionListener` to the buttons and have them call the method to update text...

For example...

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(e);
    }
});
```

You'll need to do this for each button...

Now, I suggest you put away the form designer and take some time read through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  It will give you a greater appreciation of how Swing GUIs are created and how a tool like the form designer can be used.

Learn to cut wood with a saw before you use the bandsaw...otherwise you're likely to loose limbs ;)